# create nodejs cli with multiple value and flags

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface

i've developing a simple cli services like this with [meow](https://github.com/sindresorhus/meow):

```sh
./index.js /from/dummy.txt -t json
```

i need to make the cli so can cover more command like below:

```sh
./index.js /from/dummy.txt -t json -o /to/dummy.json
```

so far i cant find any tutorial or youtube videos that shows me how to make the program can cover more command as i expected. Can meow do it? If cant, do you have any alternatives? thank you

Comment: There are multiple packages available on npm for that, for example [commander](https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved, i use commander that provide much more options. here repo:
[commander](https://github.com/dhanyn10/tlkm-cli-commander)